# bibliography style isn't consistent across entry types

Tags: bibliographies, bibliographystyle

I'm really having trouble with my bibliography atm because the way my literature is displayed isn't consistent... while sometimes it shows `pp. 30-44` other times it shows something like `10(6):1475–1493`.

I'M using

```
\bibliographystyle{plain}
\bibliography{literatur.bib}
```

Is there any way to change the style in which this is displayed? I've googled a lot but haven't come across the right way to do it yet...

Is there any way to renew the commands or field names?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! The varying output most certainly is related to varying input. Check the differences of the corresponding entries in the `bib` file. `10(6):1475-1493` is typical of journal articles, whereas page numbers without volume and issue numbers may be a conference article or the chapter of a book.

Comment: @gernot yeah you're right about the underlying input data. But still isn't it ugly that books and journals are shown in different ways?

Comment: @learnPyt - Why *should* `pages` fields be displayed identically across the `@article` and `@book`/`@inbook`/`@incollection`  entry types? In an entry of type `@article`, `10(6):1475–1493` can only mean that 10 is the volume number, 6 is the issue number, and 1476-1593 can only mean the page range. No need to stink up the place by writing `vol. 10, no. 6, pp. 1476-1493`. For entries of type `@inbook` or `@incollection`, though, `30-44` *could* represent ranges of chapter numbers, volume numbers, or -- gulp -- page numbers. If the `pp` prefix isn't redundant, it's a nice touch to provide it...